# How to check the network status in react-native app

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

i am struggling about this point, that if in my mobile i am in poor network connection, Some how i am calling the service, it will take more time to call the service

- Is there any possibility to increase the fetch timeout (or)
- How to tell the user that u are in poor internet connection.

  For checking of internet connection i used the networkInfo, But it help only for connection is there are or not, But it doesn't giving any information about the Speed of the network.

If Possible can any one give me suggestions that, How can i solve this, Any help much appreciated
 I am using the **react-native version:0.29.0**

Answer (score 11):

If you just want to know whether the device has an active internet connection, you can use e.g. [isConnected](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo.html#isconnected) from React Native's [NetInfo](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo.html#netinfo):

```js
import { NetInfo } from "react-native";

NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
  "connectionChange",
  hasInternetConnection =>
    console.debug("hasInternetConnection:", hasInternetConnection)
);
```

However I'm not sure how to find out how good the connection is.

Comment: The original question was about "speed of the network", not the connection itself.

Comment: I see. I edited the answer to specify exactly what it achieves, to clarify that it does not check the connection quality.

Comment: NetInfo is now deprecated. Use [react-native-community/react-native-netinfo](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo) instead.

Answer (score 5):

In react native 0.60, importing netinfo directly from react native package has been deprecated. You have to use **import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";** at the top and its a different package, which needs to be linked to the native code. And after that you can use the NetInfo functions as it was used previously like

```
NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
  "connectionChange",
  hasInternetConnection =>
    console.debug("hasInternetConnection:", hasInternetConnection)
);
```

Please check the Github doc for the same [React native netinfo](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo)

Answer (score 4):

```js
NetInfo.getConnectionInfo().then((connectionInfo) => {
  console.log('Initial, type: ' + connectionInfo.type + ', effectiveType: '    + connectionInfo.effectiveType);
});
function handleFirstConnectivityChange(connectionInfo) {
  console.log('First change, type: ' + connectionInfo.type + ', effectiveType: ' + connectionInfo.effectiveType);
  NetInfo.removeEventListener(
    'connectionChange',
    handleFirstConnectivityChange
  );
}
NetInfo.addEventListener(
  'connectionChange',
  handleFirstConnectivityChange
);
```

this is a copy of the code in the react-native [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo.html), the effective type specifies if the network is 2G, 3G, EDGE or 4G.

Answer (score 1):

You can use module named as react-native-offline

following are the props given on there website

**

```
type Props = {
    children: React.Node,
    pingTimeout?: number = 10000,
    pingServerUrl?: string = 'https://www.google.com/',
    shouldPing?: boolean = true,
    pingInterval?: number = 0,
    pingOnlyIfOffline?: boolean = false,
    pingInBackground?: boolean = false,
    httpMethod?: HTTPMethod = 'HEAD',
}
```

**

Answer (score 1):

This question has been referenced in many places on stackoverflow. With newer versions of react native you should use the "@react-native-community/netinfo" library. NetInfo used to be part of the react-native, but then it got separated out of the core. If you want to observe network state changes just use the provided addEventListener method.

```
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";

NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
    console.log("Connection type", state.type);
    console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
});

const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
    console.log("Connection type", state.type);
    console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
});

// Unsubscribe
unsubscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example:

```
import { NetInfo,Alert } from 'react-native';

const netStatus = await NetInfo.fetch()  

if (netStatus === 'none' || netStatus === 'NONE') {
    Alert.alert("Internet not connected.!!!")
    return []
}else{ 
    Alert.alert("Internet connected.!!! ")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expo-network`

1. Install the package

   ```
   expo install expo-network
   ```
2. You can make the next method

   ```
   const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(false);

   const getNetworkStatus = async () => {
       const network = await Network.getNetworkStateAsync();
       console.log(network.isConnected); //true or false
       setIsConnected(network.isConnected);
   }

   useEffect(() => {  
        //call the method
        getNetworkStatus();
   }, []);
   .
   .
   .
   if(isConnected == true){
       console.log("Connected!");
   }else{
       console.log("Not connected");
   }
   ```

You can read de [Documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/network/)